# Stackelberg model with 3 symmetric firms

Tags: microeconomics, profit-maximization, oligopoly

Firm 1, the incumbent, sets quantity q1 first, then firm 2 enters the market and sets quantity q2, knowing q1. Lastly, firm 2 enters the market and sets quantity q3, knowing q1 and q2.

Firms are symmetric. There is a possibility of entry deterrence, however, for this case I assume that no firm will deter other firm’s entry.

I maximize profit of firm 3, taking q1 and q2 as given, get a reaction function q3 (q1, q2).

Then I maximize profit of firm 2, taking q1 as given but substituting q3 with reaction function of firm 3. I get a reaction function q2 (q1).

Then I maximize profit of firm 1, substituting quantities of both firms with their reaction functions. In a two-firm Stackelberg model I would get some number or a combination of constants, which is not dependent on the quantity of the “follower” firm. However, here I get a reaction function, which depends on q2.

I believe that I should’ve substituted reaction function q2 (q1) into q3 (q1, q2) to get a profit function of firm 1 which depends solely on q1. I’m unsure whether it is right from the theoretical/intuitive perspective. Firm 3 observes quantity set by firm 2 but does it observe its reaction function? Usually we assume that the “leader” correctly anticipates the quantity set by the “follower” but does it work the other way?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $q_3(q_1,q_2)$ denotes the reaction function of firm 3, and $q_2(q_1)$ denotes the reaction function of firm 2. To determine firm 1's choice, maximise the profit of firm 1 subject to the constraints that $q_3=q_3(q_1,q_2)$ and $q_2=q_2(q_1)$ i.e. if $P^d(Q)$ denotes the inverse demand and $C_1(q_1)$ is the cost function then optimal $q_1$ solves the following problem:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{q_1} \ q_1P^d(q_1+q_2(q_1)+q_3(q_1,q_2(q_1)))-C_1(q_1)\end{eqnarray*}
Observe that the solution is not a function of $q_2$ since the objective is just a function of $q_1$.